# Five tricks to avoid unwholesome kamma

Tags: karma, pali-canon

I have heard of five tricks/methods which could be used to avoid performing unwholesome kamma. I can remember three of them precisely. Would like to know all 5 listed in order.  One is shifting the mind away from the unwholesome thought, another is finding the root cause, another is thinking of consequences.

Answer (score 1):

[Vitakka Saṇṭhāna Sutta](http://themindingcentre.org/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/1.6-Vitakka-Santhana-S-m20.pdf) gives the following 5:

1. Replace the unwholesome thoughts with wholesome thoughts
2. Examine the drawback of unwholesome thoughts
3. One sould forget unwholesome thoughts
4. One should try to still the source of unwholesome thoughts
5. Subdue the unwholesome thoughts